# sort: string comparison failed Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character

Tags: string, sorting, unix, cygwin, uniq

I'm trying to use the following command on a text file:

```
$ sort <m.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr >m.dict
```

However I get the following error message:

```
sort: string comparison failed: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
sort: Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem.
sort: The strings compared were ‘enwedig\r’ and ‘mwy\r’.
```

I'm using Cygwin on Windows 7 and was having trouble earlier editing m.txt to put each word within the file on a new line. Please see:

[Using AWK to place each word in a text file on a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291088/using-awk-to-place-each-word-in-a-text-file-on-a-new-line/36291303#36291303)

I'm not sure if I'm getting these errors due to this, or because m.txt contains characters from the Welsh alphabet (When I was working with Welsh text in Python, I was required t change the encoding to 'Latin-1').

I tried following the error message's advice and changing LC_ALL='C' however this has not helped. Can anyone elaborate on the errors I'm receiving and provide any advice on how I might go about trying to solve this problem.

UPDATE:

When trying dos2unix, errors were being displayed about invalid characters at certain lines. It turns out these were not Welsh characters, but other strange characters (arrows etc). I went through my text file removing these characters until I was able to use the dos2unix command without error. However, after using the dos2unix command all the text was concatenated (no spaces/newlines or anything, whereas it should have been so that each word in the file was on a seperate line) I then used unix2dos and the text file was back to normal. How can I each word on its own individual line and use the sort command without it giving me errors about '\r' characters?

Comment: `dos2unix` doesn't lead to one long line; it's only the Windows tools that don't understand Unix line endings. Don't use a Windows editor to look at a Unix file, use a Unix editor such as `vi` and you'll see each word on one line. And make sure you use the cygwin sort program, not the Windows sort program. Use `/usr/bin/sort` to be sure.

Comment: Ah I see. My problem is still not quite solved but I think now it has drifted too far from the original question so I've created another. I will close this question now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11):

I know it's an old question, but just running the command `export LC_ALL='C'` does the trick as described by `sort: Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem.`.

Comment: Same here. `LC_ALL=C sed (...)` enabled `sed` to consider non-ASCII characters for the `.*` pattern I used.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a Windows line-ending related problem (`\r\n` versus `\n`). You can convert `m.txt` to Unix line-endings with

```
dos2unix m.txt
```

and then rerun your command.

Comment: Hi, this gives the this message "dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 11451024
dos2unix: Skipping binary file m.txt" and then when i try the original command i get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @hjalpmig Do you know the *encoding* of the file? I.e. is it UTF-8, Windows code page X, some other encoding? How was this file created? Does it look fine when opened with a Windows editor?

Comment: It looks fine when opened in a text editor (Notepad). I'm not entirely sure on the encoding, but it contains Welsh language characters such as: â, ê, î, ô, û, ŵ, ŷ. I also tried dos2unix with the -f command and it runs, but then when I try the sort its the same error.

Comment: You can try if any of the UTF-8 locales works. List the available locales with `locale -a`, then use e.g. `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`. Verify the setting with `locale`, then run the pipe again. If you suspect the encoding is some ISO8859, do the same with an appropriate locale.

Comment: I believe Welsh would be part of 'ISO/IEC 8859-14'. How can I change the locale to that? It doesn't show when listing locales with 'locale -a'.

Comment: If `locale` doesn't show it, then the C library does not support that locale. In that case, maybe the `iconv` codeset converter can convert it to a usable encoding. Failing that, it's time to think outside the box: delete the welsh lines; create the file with a usable encoding; do it with the Windows tools,...