# How to correctly use sed to remove characters from file? - Invalid back reference

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, sed, cygwin

I've been trying for the past few days now to perform Zipf's Law experiment on a text file, using Cygwin on Windows 7. As soon as I fix one problem, another one seems to crop up. Please see my other question below if you want background information on the other problems I had:

[sort: string comparison failed Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292307/sort-string-comparison-failed-invalid-or-incomplete-multibyte-or-wide-character)

When I try to use the following sort command on my text file:

```
sort <m.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr >m.dict
```

I get the following error:

```
 sort: string comparison failed: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
 sort: Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem.
 sort: The strings compared were ‘ogystal’ and ‘\342'i’.
```

I believe this is due to the \342 character (and a couple of others, I've seen it show \357 also). As far as I know, \342 is an 'invisible' non-printable character.

I'm trying to use sed (simply by following an online tutorial, I've not used it before) to remove these characters with the commands:

```
sed 's/'`echo "\342"`'//g' m.txt
```

and

```
sed -e 's/'$(echo "\342")'//g' m.txt
```

However both of these commands give me the same error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: Invalid back reference
```

How can I use sed correctly to remove these troublesome non-printable characters?

Comment: I'm not sure if sed is the right tool, but to solve the backref issue, you can quote like this: `sed -e 's/'"$(echo \"\342\")"'//g' m.txt` - and maybe it should be `echo -e`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602912/how-do-you-echo-a-4-digit-unicode-character-in-bash

Comment: Maybe a better way of removing all characters with the 8th bit set is `tr -d '\200-\377'`.

Comment: @Jens I was fiddling with tr earlier, is is possible but it was echoing each line to the console in cygwin (which takes a while with 10s of thousand of lines), can I use it without the echo? And would I use your command as 'tr -d '\200- \377' m.txt ' ?

Comment: @hjalpmig, you just need to redirect `tr` output to a file, e.g. `tr ... > m-sanitized.txt`

Comment: @Jens Thanks, using what you posted I've solved my problem! If you wish to make it into an answer, I will mark the question as solved once the 2d limit is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way of removing all characters with the 8th bit set is

```
tr -d '\200-\377' m.txt > m-no-8bit.txt
```

Comment: What does the 8th bit set mean?

Comment: @Prometheus The 8th bit set means all values from 128 to 255, which is octal 200 to 377 (which are the "troublesome non-printable characters". You do know the binary number system?

Comment: Apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax using `sed` would be

`LC_ALL=C sed 's/'$'\342''//g'`

(using the bash `$'...'` quoting to interpret the character code before passing it to sed).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\o342//g' file
```

To remove the octal value `342` use `\o342`.